# Python: request.has_header(header) always returns false

Tags: python, http, web, urllib

Using the urllib in python 3.6, I have created a request and applied headers to it. However, Python appears to completely ignore that directive and when I run

```
req.has_header('Content-Type')
```

the result is false. This goes for other headers as well, except for 'Connection'. Interestingly, 'connection' returns false as well. I have not been able to find a good resource for how precisely to declare headers in Python that consistently work (and Python is apparently being extremely case-sensitive about header names), so if anyone has any recommendations I'd be interested to hear them!

My relevant source is:

```
head = {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'connection': 'keep-alive',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
}

req = Request(url, post_bytes, head)
print(req.has_header('content-type')
```

Substitute 'content-type' for any of the other given headers and the result is still false. Its almost like the default python request includes no headers but...surely that wouldn't be the case?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try (note that 'type' is lowercase):

```
req.has_header('Content-type')
```

If you use req.header_items(), you can see that the header keys have the first letter (and only the first letter) capitalized.

Comment: This worked. I did not anticipate that the second hyphenated word would not be capitalized like the first. Looking at some example headers with Firebug suggested that both of the words would be capitalized but it seems that it not the case for this application. Do you know if the case-sensitivity applies for when the headers are declared too? e.g. when I declare    head = {'Content-type': ....}?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: It seems the headers you declare are transformed to title case by the urllib Request object (not Python). I'm not sure whether it happens before the request is sent out on the network, but I don't think it matters to the server.

Answer (score 3):

Headers are *not* matched case-insensitive. The headers are added normalised as capitalised strings (initial letter uppercase, rest lowercase), so testing for `Content-type` works:

```
>>> list(req.headers)
['Content-type', 'Connection', 'User-agent']
>>> req.has_header('Content-type')
True
```

Yes, this is overly simplistic, but suffices for the internal uses of headers in the module.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

**urllib2.py**

```
def add_header(self, key, val):
    # useful for something like authentication
    self.headers[key.capitalize()] = val
```

Now since setting headers is the same as calling `add_header` on each one of them you can see that what is happening is that urllib capitalizes each key. So your header is available under exactly this key: `Content-type`.

Don't ask me why this is done like that. I have no idea.